# Efficient algorithm for finding assignable zones

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

This is an actual logistics problem I'm facing at work and I'd like an advice on what algorithmic approach is suitable for solving this. I'm looking for something better than polynomial time complexity.

I have two data structures: Container and Zone defined as follows:

**Container**

- Types (HashSet of Strings)

**Zone**

- Containers (HashSet of Container)

A Container can have zero or more types defined. A zone can also have zero or more containers. There are a finite number of Zones, but there's no limit on how many containers a Zone can take.

The problem statement is to come up with a method to return all Zones which a new Container can be assigned to. There exists one assignment rule, where there cannot be any overlaps in Container types in the zone being assigned. That is, all containers in any given Zone must have their types to be disjoint to each other Container within the same Zone.

Here is an example:

**Zone Alpha**

- Container 1, Type A, B
- Container 2, Type C
- Container 3, No type

**Zone Beta**

- Container 4, Type A
- Container 5, Type B, Type D

**Zone Gamma**

- Container 6, Type A, Type B, Type D

**Zone Delta**

- Empty

If we had a new Container with Type C, we would say that this new Container is assignable to Beta, Gamma and Delta. If we instead had one with Type B and D, we would say this is only assignable in Zone Delta.

---

Attempted approach:

An obvious approach to this problem is to enumerate through all Zones and then through existing containers types to compare it with our new candidate's types. This is O(n^2) and I'd like to find something better.

Another approach that was considered is to build a "reverse lookup hashmap" where its key is the Set of Types and values would be Zones. This allows us to lookup which Zones are already assigned for the types of that new Container to exclude them from the final list. This is much faster, but now we'd need to build a "power set" for all types as keys, resulting in an exponential space complexity. In the real world, there are tens of thousands of types so this is simply not an option.

Comment: If you keep, for each type (not each set of types) a set of zones that are admissible for that type, you can find a zone for a new container by doing a set intersection. Set intersection is a well studied operation and there are data structures that can perform it fast. Perhaps a Bloom filter of some sort can help.

Comment: For each zone, keep a HashSet of types present in it. For a new container, it's easy to check if a given zone already has any of its types.

Comment: How big are your numbers in practice? This sounds like premature optimization, IMO

Comment: _A lot_. I can only say that the current logic takes multiple days to complete and it's only getting worse.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a Type->Zone map seems to work just fine.  I'm not sure what you're getting at with "power set of all types".

To get the available zones for a new container:

1. For each type in the container, enumerate containing zones and add them to a set
2. For each zone, check to see if it's in the set.  If not, then add it to the output.

Since the number of zones is bounded, this should be fast.  If there are a *lot* of zones, then maybe invest time in a compressed representation of zone sets.

Comment: There are both _a lot_ of zones and _a lot_ of containers. The power set of all types was considered as a key for the reverse hashmap, such that we could _completely eliminate_ the act of enumeration.

Comment: Since your desired output is a list of all acceptable zones, that seems unreasonable.  Even if you didn't enumerate anything to produce the list, it's going to be enumerated after you return it, because that's how you use lists.

Comment: That's correct. Consuming the list is a non-concern. It's producing the list that I'm trying to optimize.